# Changing git default branch from master to main on command line (cli)

Tags: command-line, git

I'd like to change my default branch from `master` to `main` - I have done the following locally:

```
git branch -m master main
git push origin main
git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/main
```

Now when I do:

```
git branch -a
```

I get the following:

```
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/master
```

When I try and delete the `master` branch I get an error:

```
! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
```

On my git server when I do:

```
git branch
```

I get the following:

```
  main
* master
```

Contents on the remote (`ll -a`) are below:

```
drwxrwxr-x  7 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 21 08:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x 46 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Sep  4 12:20 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   23 Feb 23  2021 HEAD
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 23  2021 branches/
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   66 Feb 23  2021 config
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   73 Feb 23  2021 description
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 23  2021 hooks/
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 23  2021 info/
drwxrwxr-x 46 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 21 09:48 objects/
drwxrwxr-x  4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Feb 23  2021 refs/
```

So my question (finally) is how do I repoint my remote branch to `main` so I can delete `master`, locally and remotely?

Comment: Is the server using a "bare" repository or a "checkout"? (are files like `HEAD` or `config` directly visible in the repository or are they in .git/?)

Comment: @user1686 - I've added the contents of the folder to the question, although I'm certain I would have used `git init --bare` to initialise the repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change the `HEAD` pointer directly on the server as well, not only on the clones using it as a remote. This can probably be done in two ways:

- Change the remote HEAD to the new branch, then delete the old one:

  ```
  git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/main
  git branch -d master
  ```
- Or delete the *new* branch, then rename the old one (and re-push commits):

  ```
  git branch -d main
  git branch -m main
  ```

(Note that `git remote set-head -a` can be used on clones to automatically update origin/HEAD after it's changed on the server.)

Comment: Thanks - I used the top example and it worked. Was getting very frustrated as every Google search was GitHub/GitLab specific.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Still getting `! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)`

Answer (score 9):

For anyone who finds this trying to change the default branch in their terminal like I did:

```
git config --system init.defaultbranch whateverYouWant
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Still getting `! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)`